# Is the intersection pairing on surface perfect?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic surface, we have the intersection pairing on $Num(X)\times Num(X)\to \mathbb{Z}$, is this a perfect pairing? Namely, given any $f\colon Num(X)\to\mathbb{Z}$, is it always of the form $(C,-)$ where $C$ is a divisor on $X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example on a K3 surface, the intersection form is even, in particular, the self intersection of a divisor is an even integer. So it is very easy to construct counterexample for your question.

For example, let $X$ be a K3 surface with $\text{Pic}X=\mathbb{Z}L$, and $f$ is given by mapping $L$ to $1$. Then $f$ can not be written as $(C,-)$ since $(C, L)$ is even number.